# com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/NumberParseException in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 identity server 5.10 version, and when the user is registering his mobile number during sms authentication i'm splitting the user's phone with the country code and storing in msssql DB, hence i'm using  com/google/i18n/phonenumbers library in sms authenticator code. But i'm getting the below error

> FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.smsotp.internal.SMSOTPAuthenticatorServiceComponent} - Error while activating the SMSOTP authenticator java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/NumberParseException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.authenticator.smsotp.connector_3.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing, "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException cannot be found by," indicates that the class com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException is not available in your OSGi bundle or module. To fix this error, you need to ensure that this class is properly imported or included in your OSGi environment.

Can you please try adding **com.google.i18n.phonenumbers** to the Import-Package statement here.[1]

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp/blob/e72d6ae4f1dd44035d85449e16a3898790197660/component/authenticator/pom.xml#L118